# How to solve a Javascript spread operator expression error

Tags: javascript

I'm creating an Object (Customer) which is visualized with a SVG circle, so I want a reference to this SVG circle in the Customer Object.

I was trying to do something smart:

```
class Customer {
  constructor(color, queue) {
    this.color = color;
    this.queue = queue;
    this.id = Date.now();
    this.queue.push(this)
    this.circle = { ...document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "circle"), queue.newLocation(), {fill: this.color, id: this.id} };
  }
}
```

`queue.newLocation()` returns an `{cx: .., cy: ..}` object. However the error I get is:

```
Unexpected token '.' (queue`.`newLocation)
```

when I omit the `queue.newLocation` I get:

```
Unexpected token '{'
```

What goes wrong?

(Error appears in Chrome & Safari).

Comment: Are you trying to spread all three objects, or are the latter two supposed to have a key?

Comment: `{...element, queue.newLocation(), {…}}` *is* a syntax error. How would you have constructed the object without spread syntax?

Answer (score 2):

You should use spread operator with `queue.newLocation()` and `{fill: this.color, id: this.id}` because circle variable is object. mean accept only key and value.

```
class Customer {
  constructor(color, queue) {
    this.color = color;
    this.queue = queue;
    this.id = Date.now();
    this.queue.push(this)
    this.circle = { ...document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "circle"), ...queue.newLocation(), ...{fill: this.color, id: this.id} };
  }
}
```

Comment: You should never write `...{`

Comment: It's even better to remove the `..{` and write it as `{ ...document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "circle"), ...queue.newLocation(), fill: this.color, id: this.id }` but I have a strong feeling that that's not what the OP really means

Comment: Yes I agree with you. but i do this to can understand the problem and solve it. in this case `...{fill: this.color, id: this.id}` we can use it `,fill: this.color, id: this.id`.

Answer (score 1):

This is why it's usually not a good idea to write one liners. The error is:

```
this.circle = { ...document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", circle"), queue.newLocation(), {fill: this.color, id: this.id} };
                                                                                                         |
                                                                                                         |
      scroll to see my ASCII arrow pointing to the syntax error -----------------------------------------'
```

There's nothing wrong with your spread operators at all. The error is somewhere else.

You would have gotten a better error message if you were to instead write your code as:

```
this.circle = {
    ...document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", circle"),
    {
        fill: this.color,
        id: this.id
    }
};
```

Then one of two things will happen.

First possibility is you immediately realize that the object `{ fill, id}` is missing a key or it is not supposed to be an object in the first place. So the correct code should either look something like this:

```
this.circle = {
    ...document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", circle"),
    attr: {               // or something appropriate
        fill: this.color,
        id: this.id
    }
};
```

or this:

```
this.circle = {
    ...document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", circle"),
    fill: this.color,
    id: this.id
};
```

The second possibility is you don't spot the mistake and javascript will tell you the line number of the error is the `{` after `queue.newLocation()` which would make the error obvious to you.